# Nesting an ExpressionEngine Channel Entry Tag Pair within another Channel Entry Tag Pair?

Tags: expressionengine

I did some searching around but I can't seem to find any information on embedding a [channel entry tag pair](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html) within another.

When I try the following code in a template, it breaks the page and I see the opening `{reverse_related_entries sort="desc"}` displayed as plain text:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages"}
    {reverse_related_entries sort="desc"}
        {if show_testimonial}
            {exp:channel:entries channel="testimonials" orderby="random" limit="1"}
                <blockquote>
                    {testimony}
                    <cite>
                        <span class="cite_name">{cite_name}</span><br />
                        <span class="cite_org">{cite_org}</span><br />
                        <span class="cite_title">{cite_title}</span>
                    </cite>
                </blockquote>
            {/exp:channel:entries}
        {/if}
    {/reverse_related_entries}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Is there a way in ExpressionEngine to nest a channel entry tag pair inside itself?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to nest a `{exp:channel:entries}` tag pair inside of itself, you'll need to [embed the template within another template](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/embedding.html) using an `{embed}` variable.

To do so, just modify your main channel entries tag to look like the following:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages"}
    {reverse_related_entries sort="desc"}
        {if show_testimonial}
            {embed="template_group/template"}
        {/if}
    {/reverse_related_entries}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Then, create a new template with the contents of your nested channel entries tag pair:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="testimonials" orderby="random" limit="1"}
    <blockquote>
        {testimony}
        <cite>
            <span class="cite_name">{cite_name}</span><br />
            <span class="cite_org">{cite_org}</span><br />
            <span class="cite_title">{cite_title}</span>
        </cite>
    </blockquote>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Which you can include in any ExpressionEngine template using the following syntax, as shown earlier:

```
{embed="template_group/template"}
```

Using embed templates are a standard way around some of ExpressionEngine's quirks and [Parse Order](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf) *(PDF, 32 KB)*, but they do carry a performance penalty with them so be mindful in deciding between using an `{embed}` and a `{snippet}`.

Comment: I thought of this, but the current code is already apart of a embed template I was worried about the performance hit, but i guess I have no other choice.  thanks for the input.

Comment: May I suggest you re-examine and refactor your  template setup in this case? An embed within an embed is a line I would be wary of crossing!